# Android integration with Google Drive API v3

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Am trying to build an app to access files in Google Drive (view or download) using Google Drive API v3

am following the documentation https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java but it is not helping me

could you please refer to a full example using Drive API v3

Comment: Welcome to stack.  Please edit your question and include the code you are using and describe the issues you are having with your code.   "its not helping" is not enough information for us to be able to understand what your issue is.

Comment: am talking about the official sample that i referred above .. not working

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  then edit your question and share a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example explaining your issues.  **not working** is not enough information for us to be able to understand what your issue is.

Comment: Your question is Off topic for this site. Questions seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: Hello Muhamed. I am in your same situation. Have you found anything? I need a simple working sample for Android and Java

Comment: @Ton \\ Unfortunately I couldn't find a working sample